# How to write lambda function to copy two different s3buckets objects to cross accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My use-case:

I have two different aws accounts.

Let’s assume in **Account-A** i have 2 buckets. One is *bucket-east-A* in east region and *bucket-west-A* in west region.

Similarly in **Account-B** i have *bucket-east-B* in east region and *bucket-west-B* in west region.

Using lambda function I’m copying *bucket-east-A* objects to *bucket-east-B* (cross account push) whenever there’s any new data uploaded to  *bucket-east-A* by copyobject() method. Now, i need to push objects from the west region bucket in **Account-A** to west region bucket in **Account-B**, this has to be done in same lambda function with some conditional statement. I’ve tried lot many ways but failed. I’m using python language to do this. I’m completely new to IT world. Can someone please help me with appropriate conditional statement or any other way to achieve this.

Comment: Add your python code

Answer (score 1):

Your AWS Lambda function is always going from `Account-A -> Account-B`, so it should be easy.

When an **Amazon S3 Event** is configured on a bucket, an AWS Lambda function can be nominated. The event will then trigger the nominated Lambda function whenever an object is added to the bucket.

You should configure both `Bucket-east-A` and `Bucket-west-A` to **trigger the same Lambda function**.

When the Lambda function is invoked, the function is supplied with the **Bucket Name** and **Key** (filename) of the object that caused the Lambda function to be triggered. The Lambda function should then look at the source bucket and then select the appropriate destination bucket:

- If source is `Bucket-east-A` then destination bucket is `Bucket-east-B`
- If source is `Bucket-west-A` then destination bucket is `Bucket-west-B`

The rest of the code should remain the same, since you apparently have it working already.

Comment: When I’m trying to configure west region bucket to my lambda function(which is in the east), it’s throwing error. Stating lambda function and bucket region should be same

Comment: The only thing that needs to be in the same region is if you configure the Lambda function to obtain its source code from Amazon S3, in which case it needs to be in the same region. However, the actual code can connect to any region it wants. Make sure that the `CopyObject()` command is sent to the **destination region**. If you had it working for East-A to East-B, then it should be simple to also do West-A to West-B.